# Using xpath to get node value not returning value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am having getting the values of certain nodes using xpath. Here is the sample xml:

```
<Order>
<OrderNumber>2112491630</OrderNumber>
<OrderId>9876543</OrderId>
<OrderDetails>
    <OrderDetail>
        <SKUData>
            <SKUQuestions>
                <SKUQuestion>
                    <Tag>PowerOn</Tag>
                    <Question>Does the Device Power On?</Question>
                    <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                </SKUQuestion>
                <SKUQuestion>
                    <Tag>OtherIssues</Tag>
                    <Question>Please describe the issue(s) the device is experiencing in detail</Question>
                    <Answer>Im a pineapple</Answer>
                </SKUQuestion>
            </SKUQuestions>
        </SKUData>
    </OrderDetail>
    <OrderDetail>
        <SKUData>
            <SKUQuestions>
                <SKUQuestion>
                    <Tag>PowerOn</Tag>
                    <Question>Does the Device Power On?</Question>
                    <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                </SKUQuestion>
                <SKUQuestion>
                    <Tag>OtherIssues</Tag>
                    <Question>Please describe the issue(s) the device is experiencing in detail</Question>
                    <Answer>Im a banana</Answer>
                </SKUQuestion>
            </SKUQuestions>
        </SKUData>
    </OrderDetail>
</OrderDetails>
```

And here is the php:

```
<?php

foreach($files as $filename) {

    $xml=simplexml_load_file($filename) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    foreach($xml->OrderDetails->OrderDetail as $orderDetail) {

        $qOtherIssues = $orderDetail->xpath('/SKUData/SKUQuestions/SKUQuestion[Tag="OtherIssues"]');
    foreach($qOtherIssues as $a) {
        $otherIssues = str_replace("'", "\'", $a->Answer);
        }

    $qPowerOn = $orderDetail->xpath('/SKUData/SKUQuestions/SKUQuestion[Tag="PowerOn"]');
    foreach($qPowerOn as $a) {
        $powerOn = str_replace("'", "\'", $a->Answer);
        }

    }
}
```

}
    ?>

Using absolute xpath settings it returns nothing for the question group.

When I use the wildcard (//) for the path it just returns the last group of questions (I'm a banana, etc.). I am trying to return the group of questions in each OrderDetail tag.

I am lost.

Comment: After seeing your XML and your code, I feel lost, too. Please post the minimum (valid) XML and code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @michi I cut down the code

Comment: @michi Thanks for sending me to link. It solved my problem.